# UICollectionView in other UIScrollView can't touchable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

My app has truct:

```
-> UIScrollView (vertical)
----> UIPageViewController (horizontal)
--------> UICollectionView (vertical)
```

When I swipe pageView a little bit to left or right (doesn't change page), sometime I can not select collectionViewCell again. At that time, still scrolling or paging able. If I disable scrolling of outermost, then the issue is gone. I don't know where is problem and how to fix it! Any suggestion? Thanks!

[Demo source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkv4hcmr723ir3v/CollectionInPageView.zip?dl=0)

[image: `enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

the fix will be simple by recreating your structure. it will be like this,

```
-> uiviewController 
 -> uicontainerView
  -> uipageviewController (inside uicontainerview)
   -> uicollectionview (here you can show your labels).
```

By this structure you can achieve you solution. there will not be any conflicts in selecting uicollection view cell. try this and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: you are going to remove outermost scroll view?

Comment: Yes, paging will be handled by the pageviewcontroller. so need of another scrollview.